# How to show custom error in the admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm raising a validationError in pre_save but whenever I try to create a new object, instead of getting the red error as the others, I get a yellow page with the error.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Student)
def student_pre_save(sender,instance, **kwargs):

    if instance.classroom.student_set.count() == instance.classroom.QttMax_Stu:
        raise ValidationError("No places left")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError:
        raise ValidationError("No places left")
```

I've put this in the model and it worked great.